# Is there a way to find the process that started a powershell instance?

Tags: powershell, windows-10

Everytime I start my Windows 10 system, there are two Powershell process that eventually appear and they are eating up a good 50-60% of my CPU. I have no idea where these are coming from.  I looked at them using Process Explorer, but they don't show up as the child of any parent process.  Any ideas on how to track down what is starting these Powershell's would be appreciated.

Comment: Some things I would look for in Process Explorer, mostly on the Image tab of the Properties dialog: you say it isn't showing up as a child, but it might list a parent on the Image tab; what user is it running as?; some times the Command Line or Current Directory provides a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), and enable "Boot Logging" (`Options` -> `Enable Boot Logging`). Then, restart your computer, start Process Monitor again and save the Capture.

Once you did the capture, you can use `Tools`-> `Process Tree` to find the parent process easily.

If you want, you can use [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) too, it will show you everything that starts with your computer/session.

Comment: Try Autoruns first, it is much easier to use.  Only if that fails would you need to resort to Process Monitor.